# X.509 certificate file from app.config <certificate encodedValue="AQAAAAs..."

Tags: certificate, x509

How to get valid X.509 certificate file from the encoded value string from xml app.config    <certificate encodedValue="AQAAAAs..."?

Note, client using app.cofig certificate encodedValue="AQAAAAs..." works when connecting to server. So, it is valid encoded string.

Copied "AQAAAAs..." to file.crt and added BEGIN END lines

fold -w 64 file.crt > file-2.crt

keytool -printcert -file file-2.crt
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Failed to parse input

keytool -importcert -file file-2.crt -keystore cert.jks -alias "cert"
Enter keystore password:
Re-enter new password:
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate

Comment: Please check if the configuration content cert content in any encoding. Also, the file top line includes -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and bottom line includes -----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: keytool -printcert -v -file file-2.crt      


keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Failed to parse input
java.lang.Exception: Failed to parse input
 at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.printCertFromStream(Main.java:2560)
 at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doPrintCert(Main.java:2709)
 at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1134)
 at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:379)
 at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:372)

Comment: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Unable to initialize, java.io.IOException: extra data given to DerValue constructor
 at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:198)
 at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.parseX509orPKCS7Cert(X509Factory.java:475)
 at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificates(X509Factory.java:360)
 at

Comment: java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificates(CertificateFactory.java:462)
 at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.printCertFromStream(Main.java:2558)
 ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: extra data given to DerValue constructor
 at sun.security.util.DerValue.init(DerValue.java:410)
 at sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:295)
 at sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:306)
 at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:195)